# Duda Java: .Equals()

Tags: java, comparaciones

en el trabajo estoy usando Java y tengo que usar frecuentemente la función equals().

Mi pregunta es ¿Cuál es la diferencia entre

```
!"".equals(objeto);
```

frente a

```
!objeto.equals("");
```

En el trabajo me obligan a usar el primero, pero no entiendo el porqué.

Gracias.

Answer (score 7):

Si `objeto` es `null`, con la primera expresión obienes `true`; en la segunda expresión te lanza un `NullPointerException`.

Comment: Muchas gracias, todo más claro.